# Как анимировать <title>

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Как анимировать заголовок вкладки (`<title>`)?

К примеру, чтобы trkbgc анимировался символами |/-$@% и т.д.

Не знаю, как ещё подробнее это объяснить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что вы подразумеваете под "анимировался символами", но вот самый простой пример, как менять заголовок между двумя состояниями раз в секунду:

```js
const frames = ['trkbgc', '|/-$@%'];

setInterval(
  () => {
    const frame = frames.shift();
    document.title = frame;
    frames.push(frame);
  },
  1000,
);
```